Backspace on vim doesn't work after I create a ~/.vimrc file
I'm using vim on macOS, I did different tests. 
Backspace doesn't work in vim with my ~/.vimrc.
I saw that when I remove my ~/.vimrc file everything is ok, but whatever I write in it (any writable character or a set nu or anything.  When I :wq and come back to anyfile with vim, I cannot use backspace anymore.
I tried to brew uninstall vim and reinstall it many times,
and it doesn't change this behaviour. 
Without ~/.vimrc file, everything's perfect,
but with my ~/.vimrc it doesn't behave as expected.

Perhaps because backspace behavior is defined in the defaults.vim file? see related Creating vimrc breaks vim

Which version of vim are you using ( vim -version )?

Unless if i missed something but, the probleme is when i create a /.vimrc file and write any charactere inside, not when i'm using the default.vim file. So your idea cannot resolve my probleme.
My vim version is :
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compilé Aug 01 2024 20:48:53)
Version macOS - x86_64

Probleme resolved apparently, just had to add this line :
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
At the top of my ~/.vimrc file and everything work as before, i seen this answer in a Reddit topic
